# android studio run greyed out issue

Tags: android

I am very new to android studio and I am having issues with running my project on emulator. Basically, run is greyed out. I tried to solve the problem through previously asked questions yet it is still not working. Here is screen shot for the problem: 
[run grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDC35.png),
[me trying to fix via edit configrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPETB.png)
Just like I said I am very new to android studio and I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Android Studio has SDK tools installed. Go to
**File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Android SDK**, click **SDK Tools** and check that Android SDK Tools are installed.

Comment: yes. all the sdk tools required to run the emulator are installed.